# Como transformar la ruta que se muestra en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

soy nuevo usando Laravel y mi duda es la siguiente:
Como puedo hacer para que cuando se solicite esta ruta:

miproyecto.com/user/23

se transforme a:

miproyecto.com/victor-hugo

Solo necesito realizar eso, ya logré que me arrojara los datos dependiendo del número de usuario.
Les agradecería bastante si pudieran ayudarme, solo me falta eso para terminar mi proyecto final.
Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías instalar un paquete como Sluggable: https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable

Una vez instalado puedes hacer lo que deseas, simplemente agregas una ruta como

```
Route::get('{slug}', 'MyController@show')->name('show.user');
```

También debes agregar el campo respectivo para el slug a la tabla de la base de datos.

En el controlador lo manejas con el método `findBySlug()`:

```
public function show($slug)
{
    $user = User::findBySlug($slug);

    // 
}
```

Todo lo encuentras en la documentación del paquete.